# Replace nan values based on row conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my original dataframe df_:

```
 index_label,id_label,morning,evening,night
 a,x,nan,eating,sleep
 b,x,shower,eating,nan
 c,x,nan,nan,nan
 d,y,work,reading,travel
 e,y,nan,reading,nan
 f,y,work,nan,nan
 g,z,shower,nan,travel
 h,z,shower,eating,nan
```

And I try to replace the nan values with non-values taken from the same dataframe df based on same id_labels. Each column 'morning', 'evening' needs to be cleaned from nan. The column 'night' should stay the same.

For example, I write this for the column 'morning'

```
crit_nan_ = pd.isna(df_[['morning']])
df_nan_ = df_.loc[crit_nan_]
df_clean_ = df_.loc[~crit_nan_]
```

But then how do I get to the result dataframe:

```
 index_label,id_label,morning,evening,night
 a,x,shower,eating,sleep
 b,x,shower,eating,nan
 c,x,shower,eating,nan
 d,y,work,reading,travel
 e,y,work,reading,nan
 f,y,work,reading,nan
 g,z,shower,eating,travel
 h,z,shower,eating,nan
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result dataframe can be obtained using [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) & [`df.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
def fill_na(x):
    return x.fillna(method="ffill").fillna(method="bfill")

for col in ("morning", "evening", ):
    d[col] = d.groupby("id_label")[col].transform(fill_na)
```

Comment: Thank you Kopytok.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, using a dictionary to store series of valid values.

```
cats = ('morning', 'evening', 'night')

maps = {k: df.dropna(subset=[k]).drop_duplicates('id_label').set_index('id_label')[k] \
           for k in cats}

for col in cats:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df['id_label'].map(maps[col]))

print(df)

   index_label id_label morning  evening   night
0            a        x  shower   eating   sleep
1            b        x  shower   eating   sleep
2            c        x  shower   eating   sleep
3            d        y    work  reading  travel
4            e        y    work  reading  travel
5            f        y    work  reading  travel
6            g        z  shower   eating  travel
7            h        z  shower   eating  travel
```